# Is there a syntax in ZSH for creating multiple aliases at once?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I.e., if I'd like to alias both `proxychains` & `prch` to `proxychains4`, is there something equivalent to this?:

`alias prch='proxychains'='proxychains4'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add multiple aliases in one command:

```
alias prch=proxychains4 proxychains=proxychains4
```

And, since `alias` is just a regular command, you can use all shell features with it, including brace expansion. For example, the syntax `x{A,B,C}y` would expand to three separate arguments `xAy xBy xCy`.

So if you combine these two together:

```
alias {prch,proxychains}=proxychains4
```

Comment: `$ echo alias {prch,proxychains}=proxychains4` returns
`alias prch=proxychains4 proxychains=proxychains4`. Thank you.